# Can't figure out SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

In my database I have certain categories of food in a table called foodgroups. Therefore I have fooditems in a different table which relate to these categories. Moreover I created a table with orders called orders, and one "orderfood" table which defines the orders, in terms of how many of what products belong to an order.

My intention is to show the most sold fooditems in each category of food. So I want to get out one column with the categories and next to it a collumn with the fooditem which was most sold of the fooditems in this category.

```
Select  foodgroups.name, SUM(orderfood.fooditem_ID*orderfood.amount)

FROM    orders, orderfood, products, productgroups

Where   productgroups.productgroup_ID=products.productgroup_ID

AND     orders.order_ID=orderfood.order_ID

AND     products.product_ID=orderfood.product_ID

Group by productgroups.productgroup_ID`
```

So far it doesn't show any errors, but I have no clue how to get a column with only the most bought food next to its category where it is the most bought one. Maybe you can help me, thank you :)

BTW, I am using the MySQL workbench.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4b79c/2

Comment: Please post the table schema and sample data on sqlfiddle.com

Comment: Can you post the table schema?

Comment: [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4b79c/2) here is a compromised version of it, but it should do it

Comment: first stop using implicit joins, they are a sql antipattern and an extremely poor prgramming practice.

Comment: and never use a group by like that, you will often get incorrect results

Comment: well sorry, that's how i learned it at school, and i just started so why don't you rather suggest how I could improve this query instead of just criticizing @HLGEM

Comment: Because I have a job and don't have time to rewrite your mess. BUt start with using real joins and tehn you will probably have to make one of them a derived table.

Comment: @HLGEM...Wondering where you are getting that using the cross joins and defining join strategy in where clause is "sql antipattern"...This is very common in postgres world. Just curious :)

Answer (score -1):

I think you're looking for the MAX function. Add it to your select statement

```
Select  foodgroups.name, SUM(orderfood.fooditem_ID*orderfood.amount), max(orderfood.amount)

FROM    orders, orderfood, products, productgroups

Where   productgroups.productgroup_ID=products.productgroup_ID

AND     orders.order_ID=orderfood.order_ID

AND     products.product_ID=orderfood.product_ID

Group by productgroups.productgroup_ID`
```

That should return you the most ordered food

Comment: I don'T think you completely understood what i was trying to get:

I want a first column, showing the different categories there are, 
The column on the right, next to it should give me to each category the one product of this category which was sold most.

Comment: don;t encourage teh use of implicit joins

Comment: Ah, that is what I was after. I have a similar piece of code doing the same thing. It's a summary query, but not mySql. I'm an Oracle guy myself. @HLGEM, Sorry if i was down-voted because encouraging implicit joins... but instead of bashing the implicit joins, offer an example of how best practice would show it. That would encourage best practice.